# Replace serial data, which has been sent out, by new data in 8051

Tags: assembly, serial-port, ascii, 8051, vt100

I have a number counting program which transmits serial data ( three digits ) to hyper terminal. That program counts (increases / decreases) per second. 
Whenever it counts, it sends to serial out.

But, it is just adding three more digits into hyper terminal. I want to **clear the previous data** first.

How to do? I tried backspace (08h) aldy. That is weird, removes randomly.

Thanks.

Comment: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes

Comment: @Brad Can you provide it as answer. I am glad to accept it. Thanks.

Comment: It's just a link... not sufficient for a proper answer.  Thanks though.